# Слияние n файлов через bat

Tags: windows, cmd, консоль, bat

Необходимо осуществить слияние n-файлов, названия которых будет вводиться с клавиатуры, но, когда добавляю к коду цикл, выдаёт ошибку. Как это исправить?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
echo:>text.txt
for %%a in (1,1,3) do (
copy /b %%a.txt text.txt
del /q %%a.txt )
```

Comment: Для того чтобы получить набор последовательных чисел, нужно задать опцию **/L** для команды-парсера **FOR**. Т.е. 3-я строка должна вглядеть так **for /l %%a in (1,1,3) do (**